# Hungarian Algorithm using BipartiteMatchingAndCover Function

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a bipartite graph with two sets of vertices.

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
g = CompleteGraph[3, 3];
edgeWeights = {{53, 96, 37}, {47, 87, 41}, {60, 92, 36}};
g1 = SetEdgeWeights[g, Flatten[edgeWeights]];
```

I want to find the optimal assignment that minimizes the total cost (sum of assigned edges). For this I use:

```
BipartiteMatchingAndCover[g1]
```

The answer I get is {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}},
which tells me that vertex 1 is assigned to vertex 5, 2 is assigned to 6 and 3 is assigned to 4. These assignments correspond to a total cost of 96+41+60 = 197. I would have expected the answer to be {{1,6},{2,4},{3,5}} which corresponds to a total cost of 37+47+92=176. It seems like the function is finding the assignments associated with the maximum cost instead of the minimum cost. I tried using `1/edgeWeights` as edge weights, but got the same result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're right about `BipartiteMatchingAndCover` returning a maximal matching.  Instead of reciprocals, use negatives:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
g = Combinatorica`CompleteGraph[3, 3];
edgeWeights = {{53, 96, 37}, {47, 87, 41}, {60, 92, 36}};
g1 = Combinatorica`SetEdgeWeights[g, -Flatten[edgeWeights]];

Combinatorica`BipartiteMatchingAndCover[g1]
Extract[edgeWeights, First[%] /. x_ /; x > 3 :> x - 3]
Total[%]
(*
  {{{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}, {-93, -87, -92, 40, 0, 56}}
  {53, 87, 36}
  176
*)
```

Note: There seem to be two optimal solutions.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help MichelE2 !

Comment: @riveralebron You're welcome. :)

Comment: Just a pointer for future readers that the `Combinatorica` package's `BipartiteMatchingAndCover` has been superseded by the built-in `FindIndependentEdgeSet` function as of Version 10.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus is that correct? ```FindIndependentEdgeSet``` seems to return a random Independent edge set, without performing any optimisation.